How to make specific contour in data
I have a dataset of three variables a, b and c. Dataset is given as:
data = {{0.95, 0.0808514, 0.001977066786470606}, {0.9, 
    0.21307535366048516, 0.06819961070738337}, {0.85, 
    0.32350382190606547, 0.7209358859960211}, {0.8, 
    0.43623606821909267, 1.9006169970486606}, {0.7, 
    0.6611352178002029, 5.527873197468831}, {0.6, 0.8755866729946575, 
    10.541612341576702}, {0.5, 1.0704761743540978, 
    16.678565890266135}, {0.4, 1.2387553872833736, 
    23.75741639093193}, {0.3, 1.3749880236614416, 
    31.651968556200643}, {0.2, 1.4751105356700092, 
    40.26996513218407}, {0.1, 1.5362958673976246, 
    49.540218157892355`}};

I want to make a contour plot of the data with a and b on the x- and y-axis respectively along with contours of c. Then I want to make a specific contour for c=1 and find values of a and b below the contour c=1.

As a start: ListContourPlot[data, Contours -> {1, 5, 9}]

You have too few data to draw a contour with c==1

This is just an example. – Daniel Huber
